# R: ggplot2 stat_bindot alternative for circle / round points - error produced

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, stat

I'm currently using the below code to display rectangular plots on a heatmap:

```
stat_bin2d(bins = 19, aes(fill = after_stat(density))) +
```

The following error presents itself: `could not find function "stat_bindot"`

I googled the issue and read it may be that the function has been removed in latest version.

How else can I plot point as a **circle** instead of rectangles?

**EXAMPLE CODE:**

Dataset is a list of X and Y co-ordinates (in separate columns) to be plotted.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = my.project_data, aes(x = CoordX,y = CoordY)) + 
  sstat_bin2d(bins = 19, aes(fill = after_stat(density))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Percent", 
                  low = "#DDDDDD",
                  high = "#000000",
labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: Can we have an exemple of your dataset and your full code so that we can try help you ? Thanks

Comment: I tried to use your code on the 'diamonds' dataset contained in the ggplot2 package and I have no problem to make your code working, you can try `update.packages("ggplot2")` `library(ggplot2)`and trying to run your code again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the tile-like display to circles, you can change the `geom` argument to `stat_bin2d()`. Example with a standard dataset below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) + 
  stat_bin2d(bins = 19, aes(colour = after_stat(density),
                            fill = NULL),
             geom = "point", size = 5) +
  scale_colour_gradient(name = "Percent", 
                        low = "#DDDDDD",
                        high = "#000000",
                        labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>